# Cloudera Hive: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, cloudera

I keep getting this error when trying to query data using hue
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask MapReduce

From the hue job browser under the syslog tab

The error log is too big to paste here 
http://pastebin.com/h8tgYuzR

Error from terminal

```
hive> SELECT count(*) FROM tweets;
Query ID = cloudera_20161128145151_137efb02-413b-4457-b21d-084101b77091
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
Starting Job = job_1480364897609_0003, Tracking URL = http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1480364897609_0003/
Kill Command = /usr/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop job  -kill job_1480364897609_0003
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 1
2016-11-28 14:52:09,804 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-11-28 14:53:10,955 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2016-11-28 14:53:13,213 Stage-1 map = 100%,  reduce = 100%
Ended Job = job_1480364897609_0003 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
Job Tracking URL: http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1480364897609_0003/
Examining task ID: task_1480364897609_0003_m_000000 (and more) from job job_1480364897609_0003

Task with the most failures(4): 
-----
Task ID:
  task_1480364897609_0003_m_000000

URL:
  http://0.0.0.0:8088/taskdetails.jsp?jobid=job_1480364897609_0003&tipid=task_1480364897609_0003_m_000000
-----
Diagnostic Messages for this Task:
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing writable Objavro.schema�
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1693)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing writable Objavro.schema�
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:505)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:170)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('O' (code 79)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@7aee0989; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe.deserialize(JSONSerDe.java:128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.readRow(MapOperator.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.access$200(MapOperator.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:496)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('O' (code 79)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@7aee0989; line: 1, column: 2]
    at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1291)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:385)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser._handleUnexpectedValue(ReaderBasedParser.java:630)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedParser.java:364)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2439)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2396)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1602)
    at com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe.deserialize(JSONSerDe.java:126)
    ... 12 more


FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
```

Here is the table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tweets (
   id BIGINT,
   created_at STRING,
   source STRING,
   favorited BOOLEAN,
   retweet_count INT,
   retweeted_status STRUCT<
      text:STRING,
      user:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
   entities STRUCT<
      urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
      user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
      hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
   text STRING,
   user STRUCT<
      screen_name:STRING,
      name:STRING,
      friends_count:INT,
      followers_count:INT,
      statuses_count:INT,
      verified:BOOLEAN,
      utc_offset:INT,
      time_zone:STRING>,
   in_reply_to_screen_name STRING
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
LOCATION '/user/cloudera/flume/tweets';
```

data from the file I am trying to load http://pastebin.com/g7eg1BaP

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that the table was defined using AVRO as the data type but a non-avro file was loaded to the table.

Remember that Hive is "schema on read" and not "schema on load". It will check for schema only when a job is run, not during loading or defining.

Please post the CREATE TABLE command used and a few records from the file you are trying to load.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added the create table command and also a pastebin link to some of the file i am trying to load

Comment: I actually think my data is corrupt if you look at all the weird characters http://tinypic.com/r/2efs21j/9

Comment: Are you registering the JSONSerDe jar before "CREATE TABLE..."?

Comment: ADD JAR <path-to-hive-serdes-jar>;